# Difference between fast and normal Givens Rotations?

Tags: numerical-analysis, stability, matrix-factorization

would someone be so kind as to explain me the difference between the ordinary givens-rotation and the fast givens-rotation?

I know that the fast givens Rotation reduces the Count of operations to approximately the half. How is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any hints :-)

Comment: Check out section 5.1.13 (**Fast Givens transformations**) of the book _Matrix Computations_ by Golub and Van Loan (the section number refers to the 2nd edition).

Comment: Sorry, i dont have any Access to this book. Can you explain the difference in your own words to me?

Comment: There is also an explanation in [this](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN001177478) paper.